# Erro de sintaxe sql, #1064

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou tentando criar uma tabela, em meu banco de dados no phpmyadmin.

**SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'chat' (
  'id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'time' timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  'username' varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  'text' varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('id')
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

**ERRO:**

```
    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''chat' (
  'id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'time' timestamp NOT NULL D' at line 1
```

Deve ser um erro bem besta, mas como sou novato nesta área...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro é porque você está colocando aspas simples ao invés do acento, o certo seria:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chat` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `username` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```